# Power automorphism of elemantary abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I proved that a subgroup A normalizes every subgroup of the minimal normal subgroup $N$,  $N$ is an elementary abelian group of order $p^n$, $n>1$. It is clear that A induces a power automorphism group of N. In a number of papers there is a statement that the power automorphism group of $N$ is a cyclic group of order $p−1$. Why this statement is true?

Comment: You are for more likely to get an answer on math.stackexchange if you show your work. Questions that don't or lack context tend to attract downvotes. What have you attempted so far ? Where are you stuck ? What are your thoughts ?  Please edit your post to include some of this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $N$ as being a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field ${\mathbb F}_p$ of order $p$. So the automorphism group of $N$ is equal to that of $V$, which is the group ${\rm GL}(n,p)$ of $n \times n$ invertible matrices with entries in ${\mathbb F}_p$.

Then a power automorphism $g \mapsto g^t$ of $N$ corresponds to a scalar matrix with $t$ on the diagonal. So the group of power automorphisms is isomorphic to the group of (nonzero) scalar matrices, which is isomorphic to the multip;licative group $({\mathbb F}_p - \{0\},\times)$ of ${\mathbb F}_p$, and this is cyclic of order $p-1$.